# What's the difference between "English" and "UnEnglish" languages in Unepic?

Tags: unepic

I don't feel like playing the game in both languages just to check the differences myself.

Is there any special change in dialogue with NPC's between those two languages? Or is it just different spelling of certain words?

If someone could provide screenshots of same part of the dialogue with any NPC on both languages that would be good too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UnEnglish** is the original English translation done for the game. As you might know, the creator of the game is from Spain, and English is not his first language. That's why the quality of that initial translation is not so good, in terms of grammar and vocabulary. After the game started gaining popularity, the original translation was corrected by a native English speaker, as can be seen in the "About" section:

> This game has been translated from Unenglish to English by:
>
> - Christopher Mathieu

The original English translation remained as **UnEnglish**, just for fun.

The main differences between both translations can be found at the very beggining, and I grabbed some screenshots to show them:

- **Grammar errors**: things which are just wrong. "Whatever please me" becomes "Whatever pleases me".

[image: UnEnglish grammar error]
[image: English grammar corrected]

- **Literal translations**: my first language is also Spanish, so I can recognize some of the word-by-word translations, forming expressions that aren't grammatically wrong but they will sound really strange for almost every other English speaker. "Throw dices" is literally "Tirar los dados" in Spanish, and it feels more natural in the English correction "Roll a d20".

[image: UnEnglish literal translation]
[image: English literal translation]

- **Overall changes**: for example, some *geek* references have been updated, as it can be seen in the initial conversation. "Hey, in all videogames skeletons can be killed using arrows" becomes "Hey, it works in Legend of Zelda". As I haven't played the whole game in English or UnEnglish, I don't know how often the dialogs have been updated this way, but I **guess** that most of the changes have been made to avoid "localized jokes" that people outside the Spain wouldn't get, or just adding some extra geek references like the Zelda example.

[image: UnEnglish old reference]
[image: English new reference]

**Conclusion**: UnEnglish version should only be played out of curiosity, but it will  mostly look like crappy English for the ones who can speak proper English, and more geek references means more fun, so go for the English version.

Comment: Thanks! I like the amount of work you've put into the answer. I'm playing on English now, i guess i might play it all over on UnEnglish if I'll still feel like playing the game after i beat it the first time.